# Minecraft play with the same account on multiple PCs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've bought Minecraft on one PC. How can I download it again and use it on a different PC?

When I go to download Minecraft from the [Minecraft official download](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-windows10) it prompts me a page that states that I have to buy the game in order to download it.

Comment: That's because you're not logged in.

Comment: that's the thing. I can't find my account. 
and on my mobile and tablet i'm logged in via my Microsoft Account

Comment: Then that's your real problem. Reset your password or contact customer support. Also, you can only download Minecraft legitimately and safely from minecraft.net. The login there is Minecraft specific, not your Microsoft account.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should log in with the account that you use on the other pc and then you can download it be aware that you can not take a mobile acount because the licenses are different there

Comment: This is incorrect. There is a difference between Minecraft Java Edition, which is PC only, and Minecraft Bedrock Edition, which is mobile, Switch, XBOX, and win10. In the case that you use windows 10 edition, you can log in with your mobile account. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: yea you rigte but i rite that